# Instagram API - 400 APINotFoundError for age-gated accounts only from EC2 server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2, instagram, instagram-api

I'm having an issue where API Endpoint requests from any EC2 server are failing when requesting data for age-gated '**Over 18**' accounts. Note that all other requests for 'regular accounts' work without trouble. In this case, it's for a request for an alcohol brand's Instagram data, with the request being:

`curl "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/312026314?access_token=XXX"`

On local, and on a non-EC2 hosted server, I get the expected result:

`{"data": {"id": "312026314", "username": "jackdaniels_us", "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12519626_1324106037616151_2073859628_a.jpg", "full_name": "Jack Daniel's", "bio": "Live Freely. Drink Responsibly. For legal drinking age only. Bit.ly/PostGuide_EN. TN Whiskey, 40% ABV. JD Distillery, Lynchburg, TN. \u00a9\u00ae 2017", "website": "http://www.jackdaniels.com/", "is_business": true, "counts": {"media": 687, "follows": 16, "followed_by": 275149}}, "meta": {"code": 200}}`

But on any EC2 server I get the following response:

`{"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "APINotFoundError", "error_message": "this user does not exist"}}`

Note that I have already marked the Instagram account who's access token is being used here as 'Over 18'. I've tried forcing the IP address to match that which is used on the 'working servers', and forced the HTTP version to match. I've also tried the request from EC2 servers in various locations, with the same result. This appears to be a blanket block of all EC2 servers to Instagram age-gated accounts.

**Is there a known cause or recommended solution for this issue?**
(or any suggestions as to how I can go about narrowing down the issue?

I'm likely to go with using a proxy for these failing 400 requests but it adds a layer of complexity to the project that I'd much rather avoid. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to obtain an answer to this.

If you are using AWS EC2, and you are using the Instagram API to perform requests relating to an alcohol brand (one that is age-gated), then **the access token being used must belong to an Instagram account that is linked to a Facebook account**.

There are two methods to mark your Instagram account as over 18: either indirectly via being linked to Facebook, or by the Instagram app prompting you within the mobile app, when you are trying to view an age-gated account.

In my case, the Instagram accounts who's access token were being used for the requests, were stated to be 'over 18' via the in-app prompt. They were not linked to a Facebook account. Upon linking these accounts to a Facebook profile, requests to 'over 18' accounts immediately worked.

To clarify, the 'Facebook linked' method of age-gating appears to only be a strict requirement for requests coming from EC2. For non-AWS hosted servers, or your local development setup, the 'in-app' method is sufficient.

How was this figured out? By testing with an account that happened to be Facebook linked, seeing requests from EC2 work - then going through the various ways in which the working account differs from the accounts I had been testing with.